# ものか in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

Person 1:まさか走って現場まで向かうとは

person 2:他にどうすんだよ

Person 1:てっきり先生なら空も飛べる**ものか**と (思った)

I just wanna make sure im understanding this right, that ものか is basically satire right?
my attempt on translation:

Person 1:Oh! to think that we are running and heading straight to the actual spot.

Person 2:What else you wanna do?

Person 1: well, if you are my sensei, i thought as if you could fly or something

Basically, that ものか in this sentence is basically something along the lines of "as if you could fly"?

Comment: One punch man right?

Answer (score 2):

It's ものだ, but だ has been replaced by a question marker か to decrease the level of certainty. ものだ can express something is a natural or ("general") expectation based on common sense.

- [How to parse 親も辞書を買ってやったかいがあるってもんだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28872/5010)
- [Why should I use わけだ and not ものだ in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49130/5010)

> てっきり先生なら空も飛べるもの**か**と。
> てっきり先生なら空も飛べるもの**だ**と。
>
> I *naturally* thought you could fly in the sky(, can't you?)
> I had completely believed you could *of course* fly...

Unless I have missed something, ものだ never means "as if ...".

Comment: ものだか also acceptable? if yes, whats the difference?, if not, why?

Comment: @jiribrambora だか [can appear in embedded questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010), but か basically works by replacing だ.